# WPF Binding to items within a dictionary by key?

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, dictionary

I can bind to a collection item using index:

```xml
<TextBlock FontStyle="Italic"  Text="{Binding Path=Exchanges[0].Name}" />
```

but what about using a dictionary key?

```xml
Path=Exchanges['AMEX'].Name
```

Answer (score 71, accepted):

yep.. works like a charm

```
<TextBlock FontStyle="Italic"  Text="{Binding Path=ExchangesDictionary[AMEX].Name}" />
```

Comment: didn't work for me though. My Dictionary was something like Dictionary<string, IconPositionDetails> IconDetails and doesn't work when I use this Content="{Binding Path=IconDetails.x}" or Content="{Binding Path=IconDetails.IconPositionDetails.x}" any idea?

Comment: Thanks. This helped a lot

Comment: @JaysonRagasa Your binding path does not supply a key, you still need `[string]`.

Comment: Thanks, it works at run time. but at design time XAML throws an error of: "Invalid property path syntax".