# TabItem DataTemplate with binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding

I have a `TabControl` in my app. I'd like to have as many `TabItems` as many entries are in my dictionary.

Here's my dictionary:

```
public Dictionary<string , ObservableCollection<PerformanceCounter>> Counters
{
    get { return _Counters; }
}
Dictionary<string, ObservableCollection<PerformanceCounter>> _Counters = new Dictionary<string , ObservableCollection<PerformanceCounter>>();
```

Every entry has a string key and ObservableCollection of PerformanceCounter objects. Important thing is the fact that every PerformanceCounter object has properties: CounterName and InstanceName - I'll need these two to display them.

Now, to my XAML:

```
<TabItem Header="Memory">
    <Grid Name="RAMGrid">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
            <RowDefinition  Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <ListBox Name="RAMListBox" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Memory, Mode=OneWay}" SelectionMode="Multiple" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#FF8B8B8B" SelectionChanged="RAMListBox_SelectionChanged">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock>
                        <Run Text="{Binding CounterName, Mode=OneWay}" />
                        <Run Text="{Binding InstanceName, Mode=OneWay}" />
                    </TextBlock>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>                                         
        <Button Name="RAMSelectAllButton" Margin="0,10,0,0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Click="RAMSelectAllButton_Click" >
            <TextBlock Text="SELECT ALL"/>
        </Button>
        <Button Name="RAMUnSelectAllButton" Margin="0,10,0,0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Click="RAMUnSelectAllButton_Click" >
            <TextBlock Text="UNSELECT ALL"/>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</TabItem>
```

That's what I did and, as you might already know, it does not work. The above code is only for one entry of my dictionary, where the key is "Memory".

In my code I set DataContext:

```
this.DataContext = appData.Counters;
```

appData.Counters is that dictionary I presented at the beginning.

Here's what I'd like to achieve:
No matter how many entries there are in my dictionary, my TabControl would display TabItem for each of them.
Each TabItem has a ListBox and 2 buttons. I'll need too be able to access those (in order to clear the list and to have click event for each button).

I really don't know how to do it, I hope you can help me out.

Comment: Is the number of items in your dictionary going to change at runtime?

Comment: No, it's not gonna change

Comment: then check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2981046/wpf-binding-to-items-within-a-dictionary-by-key

Comment: I would be very grateful if someone just told me how to bind to my dictionary correctly (even without datatemplate - for now i can manually add as many TabItems as I need). That's most important for me.

Comment: @Arie I tried, that. here's what I did: I bound my ListBox to Counters. Then in my textBlock I did this:                                    <TextBlock>
                                        <Run Text="{Binding [Processor].CounterName, Mode=OneWay}" />
                                        <Run Text="{Binding [Processor].InstanceName, Mode=OneWay}" />
                                    </TextBlock> This example is for the key "Processor" in my dictionary. It didn't work - listbox is empty

Comment: I managed to display the data correctly. i bound ListBox to Path=Counters[processor]. Then my TextBlock:                                    <TextBlock>
                                        <Run Text="{Binding Path=CounterName, Mode=OneWay}" />
                                        <Run Text="{Binding Path=InstanceName, Mode=OneWay}" />
                                    </TextBlock>

Comment: Now, there is a problem: turns out number of items in dictionary is going to be changed during runtime. Items will be added to dictionary once the button is clicked. Currently my solution works only, if the items are added to the dictionary right after i start the program. I'd like to be able to display the items after clicking the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Binding TabControl to items in Dictionary:

```
<Window.Resources>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="templateForTheContent" >
        <StackPanel>
            <ListBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="0" 
                     ItemsSource="{Binding Value, Mode=OneWay}"
                     SelectionMode="Multiple"
                         BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#FF8B8B8B">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <TextBlock>
                                    <Run Text="{Binding CounterName, Mode=OneWay}" />
                                    <Run Text="{Binding InstanceName, Mode=OneWay}" />
                        </TextBlock>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="templateForTheHeader" >
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Key}"/>
    </DataTemplate>

</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <TabControl TabStripPlacement="Left"  VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Counters}"
        ContentTemplate="{StaticResource templateForTheContent}"
        ItemTemplate="{StaticResource templateForTheHeader}">
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

Now, Dictionary is not observable so if items will be added/removed during runtime, you may consider using something like [ObservableDictionary](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/shimmy/2010/12/26/observabledictionarylttkey-tvaluegt-c/) instead

Comment: is there an alternative to using ObservableDictionary? I tried using it, but I get exception that leads to the code of ObservableDictionary class. Maybe there is a possibility to manually trigger change notification each time i add something to the dictionary?

Comment: Sure, you simply need to implement INotifyCollectionChanged-interface. This can be done inheriting from say a List<Counter>. Nice side-effect: you'll end up having all the nice LINQ-extensions that the basic ObservableCollection does not have.

Comment: @Loreno are you positive you have to use a dictionary? Somtimes is simpler to just use the ObservableCollection instead, or something else that implements INotifyCollectionChanged

Comment: I changed my code a little bit, so that now i don't use Dictionary. Now I have ObservableColection<ObservableColection<PerformanceCounter>>

Comment: I'll try to apply the above solution to my current situation, but I hope someone could help me with that. Binding is really hard for me

Comment: I tried to use your solution (with my current ObservableColection<ObservableColection<PerformanceCounter>>) and it doesn't fully work. i changed binding in templateForTheHeader to CategoryName (it's a property inside every PerformanceCounter object) and it displays correctly. If I have 2 entries in my Counters ObservableCollection it displays two tabs with correct names. But the content is empty. I bound my ListBox to Counters and TextBlock to CounterName and instanceName.

Comment: Sorry for so many comments, but I DID IT!!! I'll put my solution as another answer. I'll mark your answer as a solution, because your code really helped me. If you have time, could you look at my answer?

Comment: Add the property IsSelected to your PerformanceCounter class, then bind it to IsSelected property of your listbox as is shown here http://stackoverflow.com/a/803256/891715

Comment: @Arie, I actually managed to get the selected items from each listbox (I used event SelectionChanged and from that i cast sender object to the ListBox and get all the selections). However, I have another problem: whenever I switch tabs in my TabControl - selections in the previos tab's ListBox are reset - so when i get back to the previous Tab the ListBox doesn't have any selections. My current XAML is below in my answer. And another thing; PerformanceCounter is not my class - it's a part of .NET, so i can't add anything to it (it's sealed)

Comment: That's why I suggested binding to IsSelected property. The selection won't be reset then as long as IsSelected=true. If the PerformanceCounter class is sealed, you may use a wrapper class around it (remember to implement INotifyPropertyChanged): class MyPerformanceCounter{public PerformanceCounter Value{get;set;} public bool IsSelected{get;set;}}

Answer (score 0):

Create a ViewModel-class containing:

1. your Dictionary
2. two ICommand-Implementations for your Buttons

then

1. set the ViewModel-class as **DataContext** of the **TabControl**
2. set **Counters** as the **ItemSource** of the **TabControl**
3. reuse your XAML-Code defined within the TabItem and use it as
   the Tabcontrol.**ContentTemplate**
4. Bind **.Command** of your Buttons to the ICommands in your ViewModel using **RelativeSource**

see for samples:

1. ContentTemplate: https://wpf.2000things.com/tag/tabcontrol/
2. ICommand https://stackoverflow.com/a/1468830/4919708
3. RelativeSource: https://stackoverflow.com/a/84317/4919708

Comment: I don't use MVVM - I don't even really know what it is, but I see suggestions like this everywhere, so eventually I'll have to read something about it.

Answer (score 0):

As i said in one of the comments above I changed my Dictionary to this:

```
//list of all counters
        public ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<PerformanceCounter>> Counters
        {
            get { return _Counters; }
        }
        ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<PerformanceCounter>> _Counters = new ObservableCollection<ObservableCollection<PerformanceCounter>>();
```

i used @Arie's solution to write this XAML:

```
            <DataTemplate x:Key="templateForTheContent" >
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="1*"/>
                    <RowDefinition  Height="Auto"/>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <ListBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="0" 
                         ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                         SelectionMode="Multiple"
                             BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#FF8B8B8B">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock>
                                        <Run Text="{Binding CounterName, Mode=OneWay}" />
                                        <Run Text="{Binding InstanceName, Mode=OneWay}" />
                            </TextBlock>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
                <Button Name="RAMSelectAllButton" Margin="0,10,0,0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"  >
                    <TextBlock Text="SELECT ALL"/>
                </Button>
                <Button Name="RAMUnSelectAllButton" Margin="0,10,0,0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" >
                    <TextBlock Text="UNSELECT ALL"/>
                </Button>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>

            <DataTemplate x:Key="templateForTheHeader" >
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding CategoryName}"/>
            </DataTemplate>

        </Window.Resources>
```

It displays correctly as many Tabs as I add entries to my Class ObservableCollection in the code behind.

Now i have a new problem: I don't know how to access each listBox from each Tab. i need to be able to read the list of selected objects.