# Binding to dictionary using enum as key

Tags: wpf, dictionary, enums, binding

I came across a problem with binding to dictonary property using enum as key in xaml file.

I have a ViewModel with property

```
public Dictionary<EColor, MyDataStatus> StatusByColor {get; set;}
```

Where EColor is as enum and MyDataStatus is my own class with property Value.

In a view I'm trying to create a binding

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding StatusByColor[enum:EColor.eRed].Value}"/>
```

and I get an binding error

```
BindingExpression path error: '[]' property not found on 'object' ''Dictionary`2 .....
```

However if I enter a digit (instead of using enum) like this:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding StatusByColor[0].Value}"/>
```

It works perfectly fine

I thought it may be a problem with "including" enum in xaml  (it is defined in other assembly) but a few lines below i can use it as CommandParameter like this.

```
Text="{Binding Path=StatusByColor, Mode=OneWay,
               Converter={StaticResource statusByColorToDayElapsedConverter}, 
               ConverterParameter={x:Static enum:EPaintColor.eRed}}"
```

And in this scenario (with converterParameter) even IntelliSense suggests enum's values.

This is how I "include" enum in xaml:

```
"xmlns:enum="clr-namespace:CommonTypes.Enums;assembly=CommonTypes""
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using an enum as an array index in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/981776/using-an-enum-as-an-array-index-in-c-sharp)

Comment: I'm afraid it doesn't :( Or maybe I don't understand how to make use of the answers.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly,Give my answer,and I have verified it.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding StatusByColor[eRed].Value}"/>
```

I tried your code with a sample and get the same result as you mentioned.
But when I try this code.

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding StatusByColor[0].Value}"/>
```

I changed the index from 0 to 999.I got an exception
"System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException"
So I confirm that there is a type casting from Int to Enum.
However,only Int can be converted? How about string?
Yes!String also worked.
Refer:
[WPF Binding to items within a dictionary by key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2981046/wpf-binding-to-items-within-a-dictionary-by-key)